# How to set up password reset emails from gmail with clearance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clearance

I'm trying to create a clearance password reset email to send from a gmail account I created. What do I have to do to accomplish this and send the password reset email when someone clicks "reset password"? I already set

```
config.mailer_sender = 'newemail@email.com'
```

Sorry if it is a dumb question, I am still new to rails and clearance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you configure a specific email address to send from in Clearance. Place this in: `config/initializers/clearance.rb`

```
Clearance.configure do |config|
    config.mailer_sender = "reply@example.com"
end
```

[From the docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance)

But in Rails, you also need to configure the server to send your email. `/config/environments/development.rb`

```
# Gmail configuration
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            ENV['EMAIL_USER'],
  password:             ENV['EMAIL_PASS'],
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

However, take close note of two things:

1. This example uses the ENV variables `EMAIL_USER` and `EMAIL_PASS` which are custom environment variables that would need to exist in your bash session (eg. `$ export EMAIL_USER=my_email@gmail.com`)
2. This example supposes you're only doing this in development (which should be true for sending from a personal Gmail account). If you want this in production, you should add the configuration in `/config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: Is the reply@example.com in the clearance config supposed to be my gmail?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Please test this and then return and let me know how it went. Email is funny. You're actually allowed to "lie" about who is sending it. So, technically, you could choose the "from" header to be "anyone@email.com", but it's not clear in Clearance if they allow them to be different. So, first test using your Gmail account. Then test another email. At the end of the day, your personal email will **still be visible** in the email headers. So, only use a fake from address when testing.